# What's wrong with `if ($num1 -eq 0) || ($num2 -eq 0)` in a bash shell script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash
read num1
read num2
if ($num1 -eq 0) || ($num2 -eq 0) 
 then exit
else 
 echo "$(($num1+$num2))"
 echo "$(($num1-$num2))"
 echo "$(($num1*$num2))"
 echo "$(($num1/$num2))"
fi
```

When I execute this code i get these errors:

```
./txt: line 4: 1: command not found
./txt: line 4: 1: command not found
```

I don't know why these errors pop up when I input: `num1 = <any number>` and `num2 = <any number>`

Comment: Shellcheck.net -- useful!

Comment: @JeffSchallerJust for fun, i copy / paste the above code in shellcheck.net and did NOT complained about the wrong if usage.... Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax is wrong. You need either double `(( ))` combined with `==`, or single/double `[ ]`

These run ok:

```
if [ $num1 -eq 0 ] || [ $num2 -eq 0 ] #mind the gap between brackets and vars....
```

or

```
if (($num1==0)) || (($num2==0))
```

Double parenthesis syntax can be used only for numbers acc to bash arithmetic expansion logic.

Single or double brackets can be used either for strings or number variables.

Comment: @Anomime answer updated